# Camlquery search form with multiples textbox filter

Tags: sharepoint-server

Good evening, I created a search form for Sharepoint 2013, using csom and camlquery, the search is made of textbox, everything works regularly, but when one of the textbox filters is not used, the query does not return any data. The search would be done in And, but when one of the filter textboxes is not used, it should be ignored. In Sql Server there exists the IIf operator. But in Sharepoint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and I solved by creating a function that generates the CAML Query.

Here my function

```
function CAMLQueryBuilder() {
    var strFields;
    var strHeader;      
    var strConditions;  
    var strFooter;       
    var numchecks = 0; 

    strFields = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Commessa' /><FieldRef Name='Account' /><FieldRef Name='Project' />";
    strFields = strFields + "<FieldRef Name='Stato' /><FieldRef Name='Ore_x0020_Allocate' /><FieldRef Name='OreSpese' /></ViewFields >";
    strHeader =  "<Query><Where><And><In><FieldRef Name='Stato' /><Values><Value Type='Choice'>In corso</Value></Values></In>";

    strConditions = "<Contains><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName + "</Value></Contains>";


    strFooter = "</And></Where ><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Stato' /><FieldRef Name='Commessa' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";

  var blAccount = document.getElementById('chkAccount').checked;
    if (blAccount == true) {
        strAccount = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Account' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq>";
        numchecks = numchecks + 1
    }
    else {
        strAccount = "";
    }


    var blProject = document.getElementById('chkProject').checked;
    if (blProject == true){
        strProject = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Project' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq>";
        numchecks = numchecks + 1
    }
    else {
        strProject = "";
    }

    var blPotenziale = document.getElementById('chkPotenziali').checked;
    if (blPotenziale == true){
        strHeader = "<Query><Where><And><In><FieldRef Name='Stato' /><Values><Value Type='Choice'>In corso</Value><Value Type='Choice'>Potenziale</Value></Values></In>";
    }
    else{
        strHeader = "<Query><Where><And><In><FieldRef Name='Stato' /><Values><Value Type='Choice'>In corso</Value></Values></In>";
    }


    switch (numchecks) {
        case 0: // non devo modificare nulla 
            break;
        case 1: 
            strConditions = strConditions.replace("<Contains>","<Or><Contains>");
            strFooter = strFooter.replace("</And>","</Or></And>");
            break;
        case 2: 
            strConditions = strConditions.replace('<Contains>', '<Or><Contains>');
            strConditions = strConditions.replace('</Contains>', '</Contains><Or>');
            strFooter = strFooter.replace('</And>', '</Or></Or></And>');
            break;
     }

    return strFields + strHeader + strConditions + strAccount + strProject + strFooter;


};
```